# Unable to run a single/specific .spec.ts file through angular cli using ng test --include option

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, angular-cli, karma-runner

I am trying to run a single .spec file in my ionic/angular project by using following command:

> ng test
> --include="/home/usama/Documents/Vanguard-Office/PrimeTutor/PrimeTutorClient/src/app/login/login.page.spec.ts"
> --source-map=false

or by replacing absolute path with relative path.

When I execute this command all spec file are being run as can be seen in cli:

[image]

```
This is my test.ts file:

// This file is required by karma.conf.js and loads recursively all the .spec and framework files

import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

declare const require: any;

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking the `include` flag adds to the `context` in `test.ts`.

To run just one file, try this:

```
// This file is required by karma.conf.js and loads recursively all the .spec and framework files

import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

declare const require: any;

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
// Then we find all the tests.
// !! change the line below Regex !!
const context = require.context('./', true, /\login.page.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
```

You can of course just put a `fdescribe` on the test file in question as well but I think that would compile everything and this may not be what you want.